# Interrupt a single cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I'm using cucumber (cucumber-rails 1.4.2). I can kill an entire cucumber command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and get "Exiting... Interrupt again to exit immediately.", but I'd like to interrupt just an individual recalcitrant test and continue running the rest of the tests.

Is there any way to do this, such as a configuration setting or adding an additional gem?

Comment: would skipping the test suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/skip-scenario

Comment: The problem is that you have to know in advance which tests cause trouble.

Comment: Is it not the same test? Wouldn't it make more sense to identify the root cause of why a tests isn't working and fix that?